# Determine whether the series converges: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n^{1+1/n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}  \dfrac{1}{n^{1+1/n}}  $

I believe it diverges. But I am having trouble comparing it to another series which also diverges and whose terms are less than the original series. If need to show that the series diverges

Comment: every series converges or diverges, so yes

Comment: Use *limit* comparison, not comparison!

Comment: @CarryonSmiling: +1 for pedantry

Comment: you may want to use bernoulli's inequality to prove $\sqrt[n]{n}$ goes to $1$. ( to use limit comparison)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the interval $(1,+\infty)$ the positive function $f(x)=\frac{\log x}{x}$ is bounded by $\frac{1}{e}$, since its only stationary point is at $x=e$. It follows that for any $n\geq 1$, $n^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq e^{\frac{1}{e}}$, so your series is divergent by comparison with the harmonic series.

Comment: for $n$ big enough (for $n > N$) : $0 < \frac{\ln n}{n} < \epsilon$ hence $1 < e^{\frac{\ln n}{n}} = n^{1/n} < e^{\epsilon}$ hence $\frac{1}{n^{1+1/n}} > \frac{1}{n e^{\epsilon}}$ and $e^{-\epsilon} \sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ diverges

Comment: @user1952009: that is a perfectly viable alternative to my approach.

Comment: I didn't mean an alternative, just tried to reformulate it in an even easier way for the OP

Comment: Nice, neat, and brief.+1

Answer (score 0):

(1). The sequence $(n^{1+1/n})_{n\in N}$ is increasing. Proof : Let $f(x)=\log x^{1+1/x}=(1+1/x)\log x.$ Then $f'(x)=(x+1-\log x)/x^2.$ Now $x\geq 1\implies$ $ x+1-\log x=x+1-\int_1^x(1/t)\;dt\geq$ $ x+1-(x-1)=2>0,$ so $f(x)$ is increasing for $x\geq 1.$ So $e^{f(x)}$ is increasing for $x\geq 1.$

(2). Since $(x_n)_n=(n^{-1-1/n})_{n\in N}$ is a positive  decreasing sequence, apply the Cauchy Condensation Test: $$\sum_{n\in N}x_n<\infty \iff \sum_{n\in N}2^n x_{(2^n)}<\infty.$$ We have $2^n x_{(2^n)}=2^n/2^{(n+n/2^n)}=1/2^{(n/2^n)}$ which tends to $1$ as $n\to \infty.$ So $\sum_{n\in N}2^n x_(2^n)=\infty.$

Answer (score 0):

Since
$\frac{\ln(n)}{n} < \frac12
$
for all $n \ge 1$,
and
since
$e^x < \frac1{1-x}
< 1+2x$
for $0 < x < \frac12$,

$\begin{array}\\
n^{1/n}
&=e^{\ln(n)/n}\\
&\lt 1+2\frac{\ln(n)}{n}\\
\end{array}
$

so
$n^{1+1/n}
\lt n(1+2\frac{\ln(n)}{n})
=n+2\ln(n)
$,
so
$\dfrac1{n^{1+1/n}}
\gt \dfrac1{n+2\ln(n)}
$,
and the sum of these diverges
like the harmonic series.